# Connecting a 7-segment display to a CD4543B decoder

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, decoder, sequential-logic

I would like some help connecting a 7-segment display to a CD4543B decoder according to the instructions in the image at the bottom, and get the display to show the expected numbers. How is it supposed to be wired between the different letters, "a" to "a", "b" to "b", etc.? Is the idea to connect each segment of the display to the corresponding segment of the decoder, so that segment "a" of the display is connected to segment "a" of the decoder, segment "b" of the display is connected to segment "b" of the decoder, etc., so that you can then use the decoder to control which segments are lit on the display to show a specific number?

And in the CD4543B, how is it meant to be wired between the DD input as the MSB, and DA as the LSB? My understanding is that the DD input is the input signal that is the most significant bit (MSB) in the number to be displayed on the display, while the DA input is the least significant bit (LSB) of the number. This means that you should connect the DD input to the signal that is the most significant bit of the number you want to display, and you should connect the DA input to the signal that is the least significant bit of the number. By doing so, you can then use the decoder to convert the binary signal to a signal that can control the display and show the desired number.

"Pin 6 and 7 should be GND, but pin 1 “Latch” should be high." In the image it states that pin 8 is GND. And what is meant by pin 1 to be a Latch…

How does the 4-bit binary adder 74HC161 work to test the display? Is it to connect the clock input from the adder to the display, and then use the adder to feed data to the display by using the QA-QD outputs from the adder to control the different segments of the display by having the different parts of the electronic circuit/system synchronised with each other?

Then I suspect that "For inputs on DD DC DB DA > 1001 (9) the display will be blank" is because the display can only show numbers 0-9 and not higher numbers. If you feed in a number of 10 or higher, the display will be blank, since it does not have a representation for numbers 10 and above.

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: that is correct, you have it figured out

Comment: It always helps to search for the data sheets and to read them.